# Java ArrayList definition in Javadoc

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to   delve into the subject of Java Collection hierarchy and little bit confused during reading  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html
After Method Summary table  it is noted : 
Methods inherited from class java.util.AbstractCollection are:
containsAll, toString

Methods inherited from interface java.util.List :
containsAll, equals, hashCode
So, ArrayList inherits containsAll from two "sources".
I have two questions:

1. How it's possible to inherit a same method from different "sources"?
   Which one is used?
2. How it is possible for a class to INHERIT from interface? Class just implements a interface.

This is declaration of ArrayList accordirng  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java :

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
```

Comment: By extending `AbstractCollection` it inherits the *definition* of `containsAll` and by implementing `List` it inherits only the *signature* of that method.

Comment: The answer for 1 is in 2: Class just implements a interface, the implementation from inherited class is used

Comment: Since you're extending `AbstractCollection` it will _use_ its implementation, if it has one. Otherwise you'd be required to do the method implementation. `List` is an interface, so you just need to make sure you're adhering to that interface contract. It will not have an implementation of the method, unless `default` is used. In this case, since you're inheriting the `AbstractCollection` it would use the implementation in there, if it is implemented in that class. I believe `containsAll` is not an abstract method in `AbstractCollection`, so unless you override it would use that.

Answer (score 0):

***For a generic example***, we have an interface MyInterface, a super class SuperClass, and a Class MyClass.

My Interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void functionA();
}
```

SuperClass:

```
public class SuperClass {
    public void functionB() { ... }
    public void functionA() { ... }
}
```

MyClass:

```
public class MyClass extends SuperClass implements MyInterface {
    public void functionC() { ... }
}
```

The fact that MyClass extends SuperClass means that MyClass inherited two more methods functionB and functionA. The equivalent of `MyClass extends SuperClass` is :

```
public class MyClass {
    public void functionB() { ... }
    public void functionA() { ... }
    public void functionC() { ... }
}
```

The fact that MyClass implements MyInterface means that MyClass need to implement a method functionA that respects the signature defined in MyInterface. Hopefully MyClass implements such a method, cause it inherit SuperClass.

---

The case of ArrayList is exactly the same. ArrayList implements the interface List. So ArrayList needs to implement a method containAll(). Hopefully ArrayList extends AbstractCollection that implements a method containAll(). So ArrayList is actually implementing a method containAll()